# How to solve: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

How do i solve this error code:

I've tried debugging, and found out the error arises in the 2. line in the while loop of get_klines_iter(..)

Here's my function:

```
def ms_to_dt_utc(self,ms: int) -> datetime:
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms)

def get_klines_iter(self,symbol, interval, start, end, limit=1000):
    url = 'https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/candles?type=' + interval + '&symbol=' + \
            symbol + '&startAt=' + str(startDate) + '&endAt=' + str(end)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    startDate = start

    while startDate <= end:

            data = requests.get(url)
            df = pd.json_normalize(data.json())
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['data'].iloc[0])

            columns_names = ["Time", "Open", "Close", "High", "Low", "Volume", "Transaction Amount"]
            df2.columns = columns_names

            df2["Time"] = df2["Time"].apply(lambda x: self.ms_to_dt_utc(int(x)))
            df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Here I'm calling the function here:

```
 data = self.get_klines_iter(self.DATA_NAME,self.interval,timestamp_datefrom ,timestamp_dateto)
```

```html
    ValueError:                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    /Users/dekahalane/Desktop/DQN_060722/Main.ipynb Cell 14 in <cell line: 6>()
          4 DATASET_FOLDER = r'ASD-USDT'
          5 FILE = r'ASD-USDT.csv'
    ----> 6 data_loader = YahooFinanceDataLoader(DATASET_FOLDER, FILE, '8hour', '2021-01-10', load_from_file=False)
          7 transaction_cost = 0.0

    File ~/Desktop/DQN_060722/DataLoader_F/DataLoader.py:59, in YahooFinanceDataLoader.__init__(self, dataset_folder, file_name, interval, split_point, begin_date, end_date, load_from_file, load_from_binance)
         56 f = open(self.file_path, 'a')
         58 if not load_from_file:
    ---> 59     self.data, self.patterns = self.load_data()
         60     self.save_pattern()
         61     self.normalize_data()

    File ~/Desktop/DQN_060722/DataLoader_F/DataLoader.py:164, in YahooFinanceDataLoader.load_data(self)
        162 dateto = datetime.datetime.now()
        163 timestamp_dateto = int(round(dateto.timestamp()))
    --> 164 data = self.get_klines_iter(self.DATA_NAME,self.interval,timestamp_datefrom ,timestamp_dateto)
        165 #print(data.head())
        166 #data.dropna(inplace=True)
        167 #data.set_index('time', inplace=True)
        168 #data.rename(columns={'Close': 'close', 'Open': 'open', 'High': 'high', 'Low': 'low'}, inplace=True)
        169 data['mean_candle'] = data.close
    ...
       1528         f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
       1529         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
       1530     )

    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting error, please post minimal reproducible example

Comment: In this line: df.append(requests.get(url)).

Comment: Found that when i debugged the code

Comment: it seems problem is inside module `YahooFinanceDataLoader` - is this your module or part of some other module (like `yfinanse`) ? maybe it needs to install newer version.

Comment: No, YahooFinanceDataLoader is a class I've written

Comment: can you show FULL traceback? It doesn't show which line inside `get_klines_iter` makes problem.

Comment: Alright I'll include it

Answer (score 0):

I think your error comes from your lambda function.

Maybe your function ms_to_dt_utc is undefined.

Comment: No I've got that function defined, and I think it would've showed in the traceback. I assume i'ts got something to do with pandas dataframe.